# Python execution flow stops in overridden property

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having an issue with the execution flow stopping in an overridden property, as follows:

```
    class Chicken:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self._colour = "yellow"
        
        @property
        def colour(self):
            return self._colour
```

A ***delegator*** class:

```
    class ChickenDelegator:
    
        def __init__(self, delegatee):
            self._delegatee = delegatee
            self._props = [ "colour" ]
        
        def get_delegatee(self):
            return self.__dict__["_delegatee"]
    
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            if name in self.__dict__["_props"]:
                return getattr(self.get_delegatee(), name)
            return super().__getattr__(name)
        
        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            if "_props" in self.__dict__ and name in self.__dict__["_props"]:
                setattr(self.get_delegatee(), name, value)
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

A **super** class:

```
    class Vulture(ChickenDelegator):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(Chicken())   
    
        @property
        def colour(self):
            print("Vulture colour property called")
            res = super().colour # execution flow stops here !?
            #res = self.get_delegatee().colour # this works
            print("This line is not reached if using super().colour above!")
            res = f"brown and {res}"
            return res
```

And a **test** scenario:

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        v = Vulture()
        print(f"Vulture is {v.colour}")
        # Expected : "Vulture is brown and yellow"
        # Obtained : "Vulture is yellow"
```

Now, in the colour property of the **super** class, if I use `super().colour` the correct value is returned but the execution flow stops right there. However, if I use `self.get_delegatee().colour` the correct value is returned and the execution flow continues - the desired behaviour.

Any thoughts/ideas on why the execution flow stops with `super().property_name`, in this scenario ?

The following post is close but not related to this question.
[Correct handling of AttributeError in __getattr__ when using property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542177/correct-handling-of-attributeerror-in-getattr-when-using-property)

My comment below:
"In his case the flow stops because of the exception being manually raised. If I replace the raise `AttributeError(...)` statement with a `return 100` statement, the execution flow resumes as expected being returned from F to G and back to main. Additionally, in my case **getattribute** behaves exactly in the same manner whereas in his case it solved the issue."

Comment: didnt run your code it has res = super().colour # execution flow stops here !? but then print("This line is not reached if using super.colour() above!") , so which one is the code you waanted to post :  res = super().colour  or  res = super().colour() ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "execution stops"? What were you expecting *return super().__getattr__(name)* to do (given that the super class [object] doesn't have that attribute)?

Comment: @pippo1980 Ah yes, sorry, that was a typo in the print statement, I just fixed it now

Comment: @CtrlZ I mean the print statement is not executed (nor is anything else that comes after) - there's no output on the screen nor the updated value is returned. Yes, the instance does not have the attribute, the idea was to go and recover it from the delegatee object, manipulate it a bit and then return the result.

Comment: @unsinkable2 Please edit your code to remove any ambiguity by showing the code that causes execution to "stop" rather than showing code that actually runs (albeit that it doesn't produce the desired output)

Comment: @CtrlZ The current code (uncommented) causes the execution to stop. Do you mean, remove the comments?

Comment: @CtrlZ The current code is exactly that: it shows the obtained output. With "stop", the OP means the `colour` property in Vulture is exited early: the second print function appears to not execute, nor the line before the return.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct handling of AttributeError in \_\_getattr\_\_ when using property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542177/correct-handling-of-attributeerror-in-getattr-when-using-property) . The line `res = super().colour` actually raises an `AttributeError` and that triggers the `__getattr__` of the base class. The linked answer explains that

Comment: try with `res = super().__dict__['_delegatee']._colour`

Comment: @Wombatz Right, that is close, except that in my case `__getattr__` seems to be executing correctly. The `getattr(self.get_delegatee(), name)` statement returns the correct as well as `__getattr__`. It's what happens afterwards that seems to be the problem as the execution flow is not returned after `res = super().colour` for some reason. I also tried `__getattribute__` with exactly the same result.

Comment: @pippo1980 Right, this works, and it is one workaround. I wanted to avoid that classes inheriting from this last class should be aware that they are inheriting from a delegator class and should call self.get_delegator().colour rather than just self.colour

Comment: Yes, the execution flow is not returned, because that one line in your `property` raises an `AttributeError`. After that it won't continue of course. Then your `__getattr__` runs correctly and completely. It's the exact same behavior as in the linked question

Comment: @Wombatz I think in his case the flow stops because of the exception being manually raised. If I replace the `raise AttributeError(...)` statement with a `return 100` statement, the execution flow resumes as expected being returned from F to G and back to main. Additionally, in my case `__getattribute__` behaves exactly in the same manner whereas in his case it solved the issue.

Comment: Actually, the problem was related to pickle and `__getattr__`:

[Pickle of object with __getattr__ method in Python returns TypeError, object not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888391/pickle-of-object-with-getattr-method-in-python-returns-typeerror-object-no)

and

[RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object when using pickle.load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156118/recursionerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-calling-a-python-object-w/50158865#50158865)